# Does anyone know if the Control-M job designed to run stored procedure accepts parameter with ORACLE pre-defined table type "odcivarchar2list"

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, control-m, oracle-type

The procedure is running fine in the Oracle SQL developer. But when I want to run the same procedure using Control-M database job it is showing me below error:

Job failure message:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EXE_SUBPARTITION_PARAM_QRY'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Also while passing parameter list in Control-M, it is giving Parameter type as "UNDEFINED" for using ORACLE pre-defined table type "odcivarchar2list" in my procedure.

I know that BOOLEAN type is not supported by Control-M, is this applies to oracle pre-defined types too!

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I worked with BMC Control-M for a while and it only runs shell scripts, or REST API calls, but by default you need a shell script to run the oracle procedure. I never saw a control m job running an oracle procedure.

Comment: Hi, I am able to run the stored procedure using database job. The job runs successfully if I give parameters with TYPE as VARCHAR2. But if I give oracle predefined TYPE then I am facing issue its telling UNDEFINED parameter type.